# Codigo python para sumar el total de varios subtotales desconocido de una tabla

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una actividad de Treview en python tengo todo mi codigo hecho pero no se como hacer para que mi programa me arrogue el Total de la compra de variosproductos, que se desconoce cuantos productos adquirira esa persona.

```
`from ast import Import
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame
from tkinter import CENTER, Entry, Label, Tk, Frame
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox, Treeview
from tkinter import *

#Crear Ventana
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Agregar elementos a Treview")
ventana.geometry("700x300")

#Crear Frame
frame1 = Frame(ventana, bg="#bfdaff")
frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=93, height=259)

#Variables Var
producto = tk.StringVar()
precio = tk.DoubleVar()
cantidad = tk.DoubleVar()
subtotal = tk.DoubleVar()
total= tk.DoubleVar()
contador= IntVar()

#Variables lista
lst_productos = ["Azucar", "Huevo", "Leche", "Refresco", "Tortillas"]
lst_Precio = [20, 35, 22, 21, 15]

#Variables del TreV
listaEncabezados = ["Producto", "Precio", "Cantidad", "Subtotal"]
Columnas = ["#0", "col1", "col2", "col3"]


#Funciones de Calculo
def CargarPrecio(event):
    producto.set(ventana.cmbProductos.get())
    precio.set(lst_Precio[ventana.cmbProductos.current()])

def Calcular():
    subtotal.set(cantidad.get() * precio.get())

def Agregar():
    ventana.tv.insert("","end",text=producto.get(),values=(precio.get(), cantidad.get(), subtotal.get()))

def Total():
    ""
        
    


#Componentes visuales
ventana.btnAgregar = Button(frame1,text="Agregar",command=Agregar,bg="blue",fg="white")
ventana.btnAgregar.place(x=5, y=50, width=80, height=30)

ventana.btnSubtotal = Button(frame1,text="Subtotal",command=Calcular,bg="blue",fg="white")
ventana.btnSubtotal.place(x=5, y=90, width=80, height=30)

ventana.btnTotal = Button(frame1,text="Total",command=Total,bg="blue",fg="white")
ventana.btnTotal.place(x=5, y=130, width=80, height=30)

#Frame cajas
frameCajas = Frame(ventana, bg="#d3dde3")
frameCajas.place(x=95, y=0, width=195, height=259)

#Declaracion de etiquetas  y cajas
ventana.lblProducto = Label(frameCajas,text="Producto",bg="pink",fg="white",font=("Courier new", 14, "italic")).place(x=10,y=5)
ventana.cmbProductos = Combobox(frameCajas, state="readonly")
ventana.cmbProductos.place(x=10, y=25)
ventana.cmbProductos["values"] = lst_productos
ventana.cmbProductos.current(0)
ventana.cmbProductos.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", CargarPrecio)

ventana.lblPrecio = Label(frameCajas,text="Precio",bg="pink",fg="white",font=("Courier new", 14, "italic")).place(x=10, y=50)
ventana.txtPrecio = Entry(frameCajas, textvariable=precio).place(x=10, y=75)

ventana.lblCantidad = Label(frameCajas,text="Cantidad",bg="pink",fg="white",font=("Courier new", 14, "italic")).place(x=10,y=100)
ventana.txtCantidad = Entry(frameCajas, textvariable=cantidad).place(x=10,y=125)

ventana.lblSubtotal = Label(frameCajas,text="Subtotal",bg="pink",fg="white",font=("Courier new", 14, "italic")).place(x=10, y=150)
ventana.txtSubtotal = Entry(frameCajas, textvariable=subtotal).place(x=10, y=175)

lblTotal = Label(ventana,text="Total a pagar: ",bg="pink",fg="white",font=("Courier new", 14, "italic")).place(x=10, y=250)
txtTotal = Entry(ventana,textvariable=total,bg="pink").place(x=175, y=250, width=50, height=28)


#Tercer Frame Treeview
frameTv = Frame(ventana, bg="#5D8BF4")
frameTv.place(x=292, y=0, width=405, height=259)
ventana.tv = Treeview(frameTv, columns=(Columnas[1], Columnas[2], Columnas[3]))
for x in range(0, len(Columnas)):
    ventana.tv.column(Columnas[x], width=80, anchor=CENTER)
    ventana.tv.heading(Columnas[x], text=listaEncabezados[x], anchor=CENTER)
ventana.tv.pack()

ventana.mainloop()`
```

El def Total es la parte donde quiero añadir la operacion para obtener el total de todos los subtotales que me arrogen en la tabla, este tiene que aparecer en un etiqueta que dice `<Total a pagar:>`

[image]

Esta es la imagen de como debe quedar mi ventana y tambien muestra la parte donde debe aparecerb el total.

Comment: Una forma sencilla podría ser tener otra variable global (digamos que se llama por ejemplo `_total`) a la que se le suma el valor de `subtotal.get()` desde dentro de la función `Agregar()`. El botón `Total` sólo tendría que mostrar dicha variable, (mediante `total.set(_total)`) que estaría siempre actualizada porque se va sumando cada vez que se pulse "Agregar".

Comment: A la variable _total ¿Que valor se le podria poner? @abufalia

Comment: Pues inicialmente cero, claro. Y cada vez que se ejecute `Actualizar()` se le suma el valor de `subtotal`.

Comment: Hola! ya realice los cambios en mi programa y si me arroga un total, pero este solamente es el subtotal del ultimo subtotal del ultimo producto aplicado. No se a que se deba?          '_total=0'                               'def Agregar():
    ventana.tv.insert("","end",text=producto.get(),values=(precio.get(), cantidad.get(), subtotal.get()))
    total.set(_total + subtotal.get())'                                                                 'ventana.btnTotal = Button(frame1,text="Total",command=total.set(_total),bg="blue",fg="white")'                 Esto es lo que agregue :) @abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque intentaba ayudarte en un comentario, porque me parecía que el código a añadir era tan breve que apenas hacía necesaria una respuesta, creo que al final mejor te lo pongo aquí, ya que en los comentarios el código sale sin formato y muy difícil de leer.

Mi idea básicamente es la siguiente:

- Tienes una variable global llamada `_total` que comienza valiendo cero
- Dentro de la función `Agregar()` vas sumándole a esa variable lo obtengas del subtotal. Pero sólo a la variable `_total`, no a la que tú ya tenías llamada `total`, ya que esta última actualizaría instantáneamente la vista y no queremos esa actualización hasta que no se pulse el botón correspondiente.
- Dentro de la función `Total()` (que es la que se llama al pulsar el botón mencionado) sería donde transfieres el valor de la variable `_total` a la variable `total` para que se vea en la ventana.

Es decir:

```
# Lo anterior sigue como estaba...

_total = 0
def Agregar():
    global _total
    _total += subtotal.get()  # Aqui le sumas el subtotal

    # El resto de esta función es como la tenías, para actualizar
    # la lista que se muestra en la ventana
    ventana.tv.insert("","end",text=producto.get(),
          values=(precio.get(), cantidad.get(), subtotal.get()))

# Para mostrar el total al pulsar el botón basta esto:
def Total():
    total.set(_total)

# El resto sigue como estaba...
```

Demo funcionando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!! y disculpe por tantas molestias, pero estoy aprendiendo a programar :) @abulafia